# Should I use Get or Delete method to delete a record in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-routing

I've seen many questions and posts using the Get method passing the ID on the url like /articles/delete/{id}.

The route in this case is defined with the GET method.
Whats the difference if I use the Delete method and how can I use it?

Which one should I use?

Comment: By convention `GET` should not be used to cause side-effects. `DELETE` is the appropriate choice to delete a resource

Comment: Secondly, `GET` can be accessed simply by navigating to that URL, `DELETE` in Laravel requires a form post, with `@method('DELETE')` and  `@csrf`, etc, so is generally less vulnerable to malicious intent.

Comment: GET for read, POST for create, PUT for update and DELETE for delete.  I've noticed though that some people use POST in place of PUT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use POST and method("DELETE"). 
Method delete adds a hidden field that you can see in source code.
Also, you can use your custom codes in controllers.